# Recommendation framework for NodeJS based website

Tags: node.js, apache, mongodb, mahout, recommendation-engine

I am planning to include a recommendation engine for a website which is based on NodeJS. It currently has a MongoDB database as the storage layer as well.

Ideally, I would love to have an [Apache Mahout](https://mahout.apache.org/) client in NodeJS, capable of exposing the recommendation API of the framework, but I cannot seem to find one.

Any web-service based recommendation framework would be a good candidate.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's Raccoon (https://www.npmjs.org/package/raccoon), though I've not tried it myself it might be a decent starting point.  Otherwise, writing a Mahout api proxy using requestjs shouldn't be too challenging.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have decided to go the Jersey WS-route, setting up a couple of web services behind a Tomcat server to connect my node.js transactional system to a Mahout recommender system. I looked into http://prediction.io/, but it seemed like it was not flexible enough for what I wanted.

Thanks anyway!

Comment: Any packages for content-basex filtering or hybrid?